# 2 table in 1 form Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I had 2 tables . driver and part_time_available, when I select driver type parttime it'll show part_time_available field. the problem is I can't save.

it throws this error : Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'driver_id' cannot be null

here's my save controller code so far :

```
public function save(Request $request, $obj = null) {

    if (!$obj) {
        $obj = new Driver;
    }
    $obj->active = TRUE;
    $obj->counter = 0;
    return $this->saveHandler($request, $obj);
}

public function saveHandler(Request $request, $obj)
{
    try {
        DB::beginTransaction();
            $obj->fill($request->all());
            if (!$obj->save()) {
                throw new ValidationException($obj->errors());
            }
            foreach($request->parttimeAvailabilities as $pta) {

                if (empty($pta['id'])) { 
                    $parttimeAvailability = new ParttimeAvailability();
                }
                else {
                    $parttimeAvailability = ParttimeAvailability::find($pta['id']);
                }
                $parttimeAvailability->Driver()->associate($obj);
                $pta['driver_id'] = isset($pta['driver_id']) ? $pta['driver_id'] : null;
                $driver = Driver::find($pta['driver_id']);
                $parttimeAvailability->driver()->associate($driver);
                $parttimeAvailability->day = $pta['day'];
                $parttimeAvailability->start_time = $pta['start_time'];
                $parttimeAvailability->end_time = $pta['end_time'];
                $parttimeAvailability->available = isset($pta['available']);
                $parttimeAvailability->save();
            };
            $obj->save();
            if (!$parttimeAvailability->save()) {
                throw new ValidationException($parttimeAvailability->errors());
            }
        DB::commit();
        return $this->sendSuccessResponse($request);
    } catch (ValidationException $e) {
        DB::rollback();
        \Log::error($e->errors);
        return $this->sendErrorResponse($request, $e->errors);
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        DB::rollback();
        \Log::error($e->getMessage());
        return $this->sendErrorResponse($request,'Unable to process. Please contact system Administrator');
    }

}
```

any idea ??

Comment: You are trying to insert a null value into the `driver_id` field. Just make sure it isn't null.

Comment: means I need to remove ? $pta ['driver_id'] : null; on my code ?

Comment: Or allow `NULL` to be stored on that field. Or store empty string like `? $pta ['driver_id'] : '';`

Comment: I've tried, remove null and save empty string. both not working

Comment: Then allow field to accept Null

Comment: it's driver_id FK. I should not allow it null

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127354/discussion-between-andrew-vanusi-and-s-i).

Comment: Sounds like you need to create the driver record before you create it's relations.

Comment: the one that I want is create new driver record and parttime_avail FK driver_id at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look here:

```
            $pta['driver_id'] = isset($pta['driver_id']) ? $pta['driver_id'] : null;
            $driver = Driver::find($pta['driver_id']);
```

From this code chunk we can see that `driver_id` can be `null`. In that case there is no driver to find. You should only search for a driver if you have an id.

Comment: so u mean I just need to remove ? $pta ['driver_id'] : null; ?

Comment: You need to gather driver_id, but do not use it if it is null: if ($pta['driver_id'] !== null) {/*Your code*/}